# How to render Latex in Kivy RstDocument

Tags: python, latex, kivy, restructuredtext

Is there any method to render Latex in Kivy RstDocument e.g.

```
.. math::

    n_{\mathrm{offset}} = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} s_k n_k
```

I tried this [here](http://rst.ninjs.org/?theme=basic#Li4gbWF0aDo6CgogICAgbl97XG1hdGhybXtvZmZzZXR9fSA9IFxzdW1fe2s9MH1ee04tMX0gc19rIG5faw==), its working pretty well, but not working in RstDocument. Am I missing anything??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to directly render latex in kivy. I would use sth else to render the latex string into an image and then display the image in kivy.

I haven't tried it, but there is tex2pix which might be suitable.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tex2pix

Comment: Why not directly as kivy supports RstDocument? When i use any Latex formula it doesn't even show any error but only blank screen.

Comment: And tex2pix is not working,
`Exception: pdflatex could not be run: PDF, PNG, and JPEG format modes cannot work`

Comment: Maybe latex is just not implemented in the reStructuredText kivy uses. You exception might be caused by a missing latex installation. Did you install latex on your machine?

Comment: No bro i didn't install Latex, I am sorry I am beginner to this, can you guide me how to install it?? i tried to google it but didnt find.